# duplicate in updating ms access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Here is the error:
http://screencast.com/t/ZDVhNmJiOTgt

Please help, here is my code:
what can I do to solve this error

```
       Try
        If MessageBox.Show("Save and update database?", _
        "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = _
        Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim idXs As Integer
            Dim dSet As New DataSet
            Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim strSQL As String

            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb"
            conn.Open()

            strSQL = "Select * From GH"
            Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
            da.Fill(dSet, "GH") 'fill dataset

            'code for editing records
            Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            idXs = Form1.idX 'retrieve index from Form1
            dSet.Tables("GH").Rows(idXs).Item(0) = TextBox1.Text
            dSet.Tables("GH").Rows(idXs).Item(1) = TextBox2.Text
            dSet.Tables("GH").Rows(idXs).Item(2) = TextBox3.Text
            dSet.Tables("GH").Rows(idXs).Item(3) = TextBox4.Text
            da.Update(dSet, "GH") 'update database

            conn.Close() 'close connection
            reloadMyMain() 'show new changes in form1 if any
        Else
            DSET.RejectChanges() 'cancel delete
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString) 'show exception message
    End Try
```

Comment: Please post the code you are having problems with into your question, along with any error messages.

Comment: It seems you may have included the wrong error message. You may wish to check your table for unique indexes if you are getting duplicate record errors.

Comment: Is it necessary to put quotes around file names with spaces in them, e.g. something like, "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb'"? I wouldn't know because I don't use ODBC with Jet, nor do I use spaces in file or folder names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check the table in the DB - one of the columns is either indexed and can only contain unique values, or has some other limitation.

you enter a data into that column that it can not hold.

Try to "UPDATE" the Data Manually directly on the table and you will see what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just don't have the file `F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb`.

Check the path to your access database file.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you point to reads:

> 'F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb' is not a valid path.

Apparently you mistyped the path to the db in the `conn.ConnectString = ...` line.

Comment: no because its the same code that I used for adding entries, and it worked. The only difference is the command builder part and the .update